# No route found for POST

Tags: 8, entities

I've been working on a custom rest module for Drupal. I wrote the following Resource class.

```
    <?php

namespace Drupal\aker_platform\Plugin\rest\resource;

/**
 * Provides a License GET Resource
 *
 * @RestResource(
 *   id = "license_resource",
 *   label = @Translation("License Resource"),
 *   uri_paths = {
 *     "canonical" = "/aker/api/license/{id}",
 *     "https://www.drupal.org/link-relations/create" = "/aker/api/license",
 *     
 *   }
 * )
 */

class LicenseResource extends ResourceBase {


  /**
   * Responds to entity GET requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function get($id) {
    // Bla bla code for GET requests
  }

  /**
   * Responds to entity POST requests.
   * @return \Drupal\rest\ResourceResponse
   */
  public function post($data) {
     // bla bla for post requests.
  }

}
```

The get route works well, i enabled the routes using Rest UI:

[image]

My custom skeleton structure:

```
src
 -Entity
   LicenseEntity.php
 -Plugin
   -rest
    -resource
     LicenseResource.php
aker_platform.info.yml
```

To test the endpoint, i'm using curl:

```
curl --header "Content-Type: application/json" \
  --request POST \
  --data-binary '{"username":"xyz","password":"xyz"}' \
  mydomain/aker/api/license?_format=json
```

Also the endpoint was added to Anonymous guests to perform the requests without authentication.

Comment: Just to let you know, DA isn't code-debugging service and it's hard to troubleshoot code remotely. It might be helpful if you add a question to your post. Right now, you've only stated a problem you're having.

Comment: @ShawnConn Is there any other site that could help me with code debugging?

Comment: You could try Reddit or the Drupal Slack channels. Sometimes people will comment here with suggestions (generally these types of questions are voted down/closed because there's no way to answer it), trying googling for troubleshooting ideas for Drupal Core REST plugins.

Comment: Thanks for the advices!

In fact i've already solved this. I will edit the post with the solution.

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers! If you found an answer for your own question, you should post that as answer, instead of editing the question.

Answer (score 2):

You need to set `Content-Type` to `application/vnd.api+json`.

> ### Headers
>
> The following headers are **required** on all POST request to get a
> proper JSON:API request and response.
>
> ```
> Accept: application/vnd.api+json
> Content-Type:application/vnd.api+json]
> ```

See: https://www.drupal.org/docs/core-modules-and-themes/core-modules/jsonapi-module/creating-new-resources-post#s-headers